# Gradle build fails while executing './gradlew build installDist --info' inside docker container

Tags: gradle, docker

I have created docker container on SLES 12.

I have installed `git` and `java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`.

Clone the master branch of https://github.com/apache/incubator-geode.git

Changed directory to `incubator-geode`

And then executed `./gradlew build installDist --info`

This gives an error saying:
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gemfire-core:test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///incubator-    geode/gemfire-core/build/reports/test/index.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

The file index.html has following:

```
com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.compression.SnappyCompressorJUnitTest > testCompressByteArray FAILED
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load native Snappy library.
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.compression.SnappyCompressor.<init>(SnappyCompressor.java:51)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.compression.SnappyCompressor.getDefaultInstance(SnappyCompressor.java:67)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.compression.SnappyCompressorJUnitTest.testCompressByteArray(SnappyCompressorJUnitTest.java:34)

    Caused by:
    org.xerial.snappy.SnappyError: [FAILED_TO_LOAD_NATIVE_LIBRARY] no native library is found for os.name=Linux and os.arch=s390x
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.findNativeLibrary(SnappyLoader.java:299)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.loadNativeLibrary(SnappyLoader.java:163)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.load(SnappyLoader.java:145)
        at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.<clinit>(Snappy.java:47)
        at com.gemstone.gemfire.compression.SnappyCompressor.<init>(SnappyCompressor.java:48)
        ... 2 more

       com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.compression.SnappyCompressorJUnitTest > testConstructor FAILED
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.compression.SnappyCompressor.<init>(SnappyCompressor.java:48)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.compression.SnappyCompressor.getDefaultInstance(SnappyCompressor.java:67)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.compression.SnappyCompressorJUnitTest.testConstructor(SnappyCompressorJUnitTest.java:45)

      com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.AttributesFactoryJUnitTest > testInvalidConfigurations FAILED
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.compression.SnappyCompressor.<init>(SnappyCompressor.java:48)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.compression.SnappyCompressor.getDefaultInstance(SnappyCompressor.java:67)
    at com.gemstone.gemfire.cache.AttributesFactoryJUnitTest.testInvalidConfigurations(AttributesFactoryJUnitTest.java:214)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I would try to do is to run the command locally in the docker container.  You do this by running the container using docker run and adding the "--endpoint /bin/bash" to the run line.  There are some examples [here](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/).  This will enable you to do the gradlew command locally and see what the output is.

I'm presuming that it has something to do with the JAVA_HOME not being set or that Java is not in the path.

Comment: Is using SLES 12 an absolute need? I run GemFire on Ubuntu 7 all the time with no issues.