# gradle build local works. In docker container it doesn't. WHY?

Tags: java, docker, gradle, redis

The situation is simple:

here is my local env:

```
cbongiorno at wa-cbongiorno-mba in /Volumes/dev/sterling/java-user-login-service on master [!$]
$ gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.0
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-06-14 15:11:08 UTC
Revision:     316546a5fcb4e2dfe1d6aa0b73a4e09e8cecb5a5

Groovy:       2.4.11
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_131 (Oracle Corporation 25.131-b11)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.12.5 x86_64
```

here is the build command I run:

```
gradle compileJava check assemble && history | tail -3
```

here are the results:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3m 3s
38 actionable tasks: 38 executed
 1496  gradle clean
 1497  gradle compileJava check assemble && history | tail -2
```

Now, when I run this identical arrangement in docker:

```
docker run --rm gradle:alpine gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.0
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-06-14 15:11:08 UTC
Revision:     316546a5fcb4e2dfe1d6aa0b73a4e09e8cecb5a5

Groovy:       2.4.11
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_131 (Oracle Corporation 25.131-b11)
OS:           Linux 4.9.36-moby amd64

docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/project -w /project gradle:alpine gradle compileJava check assemble
```

The tests fail and in the logs I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy
build_1  |      at org.redisson.codec.SnappyCodec$2.encode(SnappyCodec.java:68)
build_1  |      at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandEncoder.encode(CommandEncoder.java:103)
build_1  |      at org.redisson.client.handler.CommandEncoder.encode(CommandEncoder.java:45)
build_1  |      at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToByteEncoder.write(MessageToByteEncoder.java:107)
build_1  |      ... 31 more
build_1  | 
build_1  | 
build_1  |     io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy
```

When my app attempts to engage with Redis.

How on earth is this possible? Is this a red-herring and the issues is related to the docker environment itself? I would guess an archive is corrupt/wrong but the docker container would pull from the same artifact repositories. So, I don't even know where to start

I used the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45248234/how-to-get-gradle-to-output-dependency-hash-for-each-dependency/45250437#45250437) to dump the hash values of every jar into a file with:

```
docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/project -w /project  gradle:alpine gradle printDependencyHashes | sort >  hashes-docker.log

gradle printDependencyHashes | sort > hashes.log
```

respectively. The results are identical. I even thought about how jar load order from the files system could effect class loading and compared dependencies. Identical. Omitted for brevity.

[image: MD5 hash of all dependencies compared]

Comment: This is not a problem related to any dependencies. It seems that you've configured everything well. My guess is that the problem lies in snappy library itself - it can't be run on the docker platform - maybe some native library is missing? Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31308508/gradle-build-fails-while-executing-gradlew-build-installdist-info-inside-d/31420215) to grab understanding what I'm talking about. Maybe try to run snappy itself on the docker container and see if it works or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java Snappy's native library (loaded through JNI) is compiled against glibc. Alpine Linux (what your container is based on) uses the musl libc which is source-compatible but not binary-compatible (basically means if you compile the native library against musl it will work, but if it is compiled against glibc it will not work with musl).

You have three options:

1. Install `java-snappy-native` (which contains a native library built for musl) in your Alpine container and set `org.xerial.snappy.use.systemlib=true` (tells the Java library to use the preinstalled native lbrary). <strike>Currently you also need to install `snappy` since somebody failed to add that dependency to the above package.</strike>
2. Use a base container with glibc
3. Install glibc in your Alpine container (not really recommended)

Comment: Cool answer! How did you know that so well? :)

Comment: @Opal I dealt with that library in Alpine containers, so I knew that specific case. Generally though I just work a lot with containers and different operating systems so I know the quirks of running different libraries on different base operating systems.

Comment: Could edit your post, [java-snappy-native](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.6/community/s390x/java-snappy-native) now have `snappy` dependency

Comment: @Lorenz Could you clarify if org.xerial.snappy.use.systemlib=true needs to be set as a Java property for the application that intends to use snappy?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be a Java property. Snappy-Java is internally just calling `System.getProperty()`.

Comment: BTW this was a fantastic answer